# No indication for which row each predicted estimate from K clustering relate to

Tags: python, machine-learning

This is the command I used from **sklearn**.

`pred = knn.predict(b_test)`

And after I used this command.
`print(pred)`

It showed the following results.

> [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]

But it does not indicate for which row each predicted estimate relates to.
Can someone help me relate the predicted estimates to the relevant row?

Comment: It will be in the same order of b_test rows. So, you should be able to reference b_test row index to find the corresponding prediction.

Comment: You're a life saver Jayant. Thank you.

Comment: @JayantSahewal: how do I create a table from this result list? i'd like to create a table out of it? i'd like to have 2 columns: 1 column for these results and another one with the names.

Comment: if you have two lists, you should be able to create a pandas DataFrame from them very easily. Then you can save it in a csv file to your disk.

Comment: @JayantSahewal thank you, thanks for helping a python newbie. i figured out with your guidance.